# WSO2 ESB: Getting Dead Pages When Running in Windows Service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm getting blank pages when navigating the WSO2 ESB-4.9.0 management console. For example, the registry, templates, endpoints, and local entries pages are all blank when navigating to them in the console UI.

I've found the following errors in the logs:

- Error during rendering
- IO Error executing tag: JSPException while including path '/templates/list_templates.jsp'. ServletException while including page.

The ESB is running in a YAJSW Windows Service. I should note that the ESB runs fine when running straight from the command line, it's just when using the service wrapper.

Strainy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that the ESB starts as a window service, in carbon 4.4.x, default wrapper.conf file needs to be updated with following additional entries.

```
wrapper.java.additional.26 = -Dwso2.carbon.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\carbon.xml
wrapper.java.additional.27 = -Dwso2.registry.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\registry.xml
wrapper.java.additional.28 = -Dwso2.user.mgt.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\user-mgt.xml
wrapper.java.additional.29 = -Dwso2.transports.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\mgt-transports.xml
wrapper.java.additional.31 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false
wrapper.java.additional.33 = -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

You can verify these configurations in wrapper.conf and these configurations may help you to solve the jsp error.

Following link may help you if you need more information regarding this.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service#InstallingasaWindowsService-SettinguptheYAJSWwrapperconfigurationfile

Comment: Hi Sachini, thanks for chiming in. Have you actually tried running YAJSW with ESB 4.9.0? I'm experiencing a known issue as highlighted in my answer. I realise the documentation talks about the wrapper.conf file, but I have used the default config file that WSO2 provides with no luck.

Comment: I got the same error and after adding above properties it solved the issue. Did they work for you?

Comment: Hi Sachini, this worked! Thanks very much. I'll update the WSO2 Issue with the fix.

Comment: This notice comes when u start ESB on windows machine "The running OS : Windows 8.1 is not a tested Operating System for running WSO2 Carbon"

Comment: and this is good thing to set "-Dfile.encoding=UTF8", if u run esb on windows machine

Answer (score 0):

I just used the NSSM - the "Non-Sucking Service Manager".

It's actually amazingly simple to install a Service using this tool. 
https://nssm.cc

Just set it up to point at the wso2server.bat file

Keeping an eye on this issue however: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4342